# Marathi letter / rakaar symbol

Tags: language-support

I am having bit of difficulty typing the rakaar symbol in the marathi language of ubuntu keyboard (Marathi - Kagapa phonetic)

Reference to this symbol is not found anywhere in the keyboard layout diagram.
(Unless I am horribly mistaken).

The symbol looks like the one below the number 2 , as shown in the picture here  :

http://www.easyhindityping.com/public/img/keyboard/marathi/kurti-dev/hr/2-marathi-keyboard-kurti-dev-1280-light.png

which looks like a small horizontal curve. This used for the letter r in marathi in conjunction with other letters. However I am unable to reproduce that symbol in any way.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you install the `ibus-m17n` package (and reboot), you'll get access to a few Marathi input methods. I have no idea if it would help, but may be worth a try.

Comment: ibus-m17n is already the newest version (1.3.4-5).

Comment: Then you should see another three Marathi input sources. My idea is that you try out those.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04 and there is only one marathi keyboard here :(

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Answer (score 0):

This is related to your Keyboard.
Go to Ubuntu Dash, and type "Keyboard"
Then When the Keyboard is open, Select the "Layout"
Now you will have to adjust the Keyboard/Language with regards to 
your setup. 
You will have to tweak in order to see which one works.

See Install Tweaks from this page:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html.en
You may also find [this](https://superuser.com/questions/59418/how-to-type-special-characters-in-linux) post useful.

Comment: I appreciate your help and effort for guiding but I need to know the correct combination. I cannot experiment with the permutation and combination of keys, looks silly. sorry but I don't have that kind of time. Do you know the combination?

Comment: Did you add Marathi to your keyboard layout as mentioned in the answer?

Comment: yes I have tried 3 hindi layouts (kagapa, phonetic and bolnagri) , one marathi , sanskrit and indian(generic) layout

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xev` to find keysym of a key you want to use and then use `xmodmap` to remap that key to rakaar symbol.

Here is a sample command:

```
xmodmap -e "keysym  at = U0956"
```

This will remap the 2/@ key on a US keyboard to the rakaar symbol.

Warning: This will over write any existing layout.

If you did issue the command and you need to revert use the following command :

```
xmodmap -e "keysym  U0956 = U0032 U0040"
```

https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xmodmap.1.xhtml

Comment: You need not to post separate answers in the same question. You can edit your original answer to include all details you've posted in separate answers.

Comment: That is not having the desired effect. I'm trying to print short ra as in paryo , as shown second from top in the following image : 

https://scriptsource.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=script_detail&key=Deva

The one below Ram. The one you mentioned prints ra in some other fashion.

Comment: If you can copy paste that character, then you can search in Google for the unicode of that character. All you have to do is replace the unicode number followed by "U" in the above example. Here is a sample unicode chart : http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0900-097F

Comment: It is not a separate character. It is used in conjunction as 'ra' with other letters. for example the rakaar for the word 'dharma' creates a rakar on top as shown in the image, whereas the rakaar I want is the horizontal curve. like the word 'paryo' as mentioned in the image above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, After some googling for a few hours , I managed to find out , that the horizontal rakaar is called an eyelash character.

It is typed via typing the character R with a dot below + sandhi character (F usually ) + ya

ie. r.+ f + y will give barya with a horizontal curve.

Thanks for your time.

I found this from this link : https://scriptsource.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=entry_detail&uid=d6dvcx2lay

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any other third party tool, like [I Love Typing](https://ilovetyping.com/english-to-marathi-typing).

It's working perfectly at my end.